# What command do I use to spin up a "power up in standby" drive?

Tags: hard-disk

I have 8 drives in my server connected via PATA. The drives are set for no-spin via jumpers on the drive. `hdparm -I` says

> powers-up in standby; SET FEATURES subcmd spins-up

What command do I use to spin the drives up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drives supporting the "Power-up in Standby" feature are supposed to spin up as soon as they get a command that requires reading the disk.  So if your drive isn't spinning up when you do something like `dd if=/dev/hdX of=/dev/null count=512`, then I'd suspect that your disk controller or drive (or possibly BIOS, or Linux kernel version) doesn't fully support this feature.  To rule out the kernel, the `hdparm` man page recommends Linux 2.6.22 or later.

References:

- [A forum exchange that looks like it addresses your problem](http://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=2013.0)
- ["Power-up in Standby" feature proposal / specification](http://ftp.t10.org/ftp/t13/technical/d97150r0.pdf)
- [`man hdparm`](http://man.he.net/man8/hdparm) (look at the `-s` option)

Comment: you're right, i upgraded the kernel and now i can spin up the drive by just trying to access it.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, PUIS needs to be supported. It requires a certain string to be sent to the HDD, otherwise it will not spin back up, not just any signal. It looks like OP upgraded the kernel and the kernel supported PUIS.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to spin them up manually?  Normally, that happens automatically when the kernel needs to read or write to the drive.  `hdparm` has options to force a drive to spin down (`-y` and `-Y`), but not to spin up.  I suppose you could use `hdparm -z` to force a re-read of the partition table, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: yes, i need to spin them up manually. hdparm -z does not spin them up.